# Ballerina V 1.0 - Get configuration value from file

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to get config values from a file using ballerina V 1.0. 
Config file as below:
[image]

And I'm trying to print value in test.bal file as;

```
io:println(config:getAsString("student.jdbc.username"));
```

When I gave config values in ballerina.conf file it worked fine with below command.

> ballerina run .\test.bal

Now I need to read configs from another file (testConf.conf)
I tried below commands to run my project but it's not taking config values as expected.

> ballerina run .\test.bal -config testConf.conf
>
> ballerina run .\test.bal -c testConf.conf
>
> ballerina run .\test.bal -Bballerina.conf=.\testConf.conf

Also tried with .toml file with above commands, but didn't work.

What's the command to read configs from a given file (except ballerina.conf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Ballerina v1.0, custom config file path is given as follows:

`ballerina run .\test.bal --b7a.config.file=path/to/conf/file/file-name.conf`

Pleaser refer to below example and how it is executed.

https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/by-example/config-api.html